# Mid 2009 MacBook Pro fan runs at full speed from startup

Tags: macbook-pro

I recently replaced the trackpad in my mid 2009 MacBook Pro. It now works fine. But upon restart, the fan runs at full speed from startup. It even turned itself on once while it was "asleep." I rac Activity monitor and nothing is using an undue amount of cpu. It never did this at any point previously. I am running System 10.9.4 w/2 GB RAM. I zapped the PRAM, reset the SMC, removed and replaced the battery. I am curious if it might be a thermal sensor related to the fan. if so, Is that replaceable? Is it possible that I disconnected or damaged it when replacing the trackpad? I am really lost here.

Thanks.

Bryan

Comment: Is it possible.  I suppose its possible.  Have you checked?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a termperature sensor located on the back of the touchpad. 
According to this link (https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/71048/Where+is+the+left+palm+rest+temp+sensor , check the accepted answer there), the "left palm rest sensor" is located on the back of the trackpad in 2010 MBPs and would cause the described problems if faulty or disconnected - I'm guessing it wouldn't be much different in a 2009 MBP.

Comment: Thank you. I will check that when I get home tonight. That makes some sense. I'll let everyone know if it works.